# Converting string to int, array of strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an issue with converting a string of id to an int when there are multiple strings passed in, the code shows the following:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < Request.Params["service"].Length; i++)
            {
                int serviceID = int.Parse(Request.Params["service"]);

                db.ServiceAssignments.Add(serviceAssignment);
                serviceAssignment.locationID = locationID;
                serviceAssignment.ServiceID = serviceID;

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

If you pass in one param, you get: `int.Parse(Request.Params["Service"]`); = 1, which then works and the database saves. however if you have the following you get:

'1,2' which three. What I want is 1 and then 2, not 1,2.

**What is 1 and 2?**

When you create anew location you get to select services for that location. The service id, in the case of this problem is 1 and 2. if I select one service then it saves and all is well. When I select two or more it doesnt work.

I though I could do:

`Request.Params["Service"][i]` because "Service" is an array after all. How ever this causes database problems and a whole other mess.

So what would you suggest I can do to make it save id 1 and id 2 when you select them for a location?

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET MVC you likely don't want to be digging into the `Request.Params` property.  You should be using a model in your controller action and let ASP.NET do the binding for you.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with how I am doing it for now?

Answer (score 0):

MVC 3 is quite powerful to figure out the binding, I don't know exactly what are you doing in the view that get the service Ids from user but I assume there is form there and if all Ids are int you can do like this and you don't need any conversion, or maybe you can use FormCollection. I don't think using Request in MVC 3 is a good idea, it does not really belong the whole MVC idea.

```
public void Add(int[] service)
        {
            foreach (var item in service)
            {
                int serviceID = item;
            }
        }
```

OR

```
 public void Add(FormCollection frm)
        {
            foreach (var item in frm.AllKeys)
            {
                if (item.StartsWith("service"))
                {
                    int serviceID = Int32.Parse(frm[item]);
                }
            }
        }
```

anyway none of these are also MVC, these are should work but I recommend you to use Models in views and controllers

Answer (score -1):

This will work.  Just tested it:

```
string[] items = Request.Params["service"].Split(','); 

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    int serviceID = int.Parse(items[i]);
    db.ServiceAssignments.Add(serviceAssignment);
    serviceAssignment.locationID = locationID;
    serviceAssignment.ServiceID = serviceID;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

As a side note, I'd probably make two changes:

1. I'd use a foreach statement.  No real difference; just less typing.
2. I'd put the SaveChanges() AFTER the for loop.  This will make fewer calls to the database, but still accomplish the same thing.

Comment: It states that it cannot convert from string to char[] on the split part of the conversation. `Request.Params["service"].Split(",");` throws the error.

Comment: Sorry, I inadvertently used double instead of single quotes inside the split function call.  Edited version above will work for you.